# How to use CAGradientLayers on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, cagradientlayer

I am running into a problem with using CAGradientLayers on my UITableViewCells. What I am attempting to do is simulate what actionsForRowAtIndexPath does, but I want to use a custom action view rather than just setting a background color.

So, my plan of action is in my UITableViewCell I have laid out a UIView (the action view) that is hidden beneath another UIView (main content view) that are both in the default contentView of UITableViewCell.

So in my 'cellForRowAt' tableView function, I have this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Set Up Gradient
    let actionGradient = CUSTOM_GRADIENTS.blueToGreen!
    actionGradient.frame = cell.actionView.frame

    // Add Gradient to ActionView
    cell.actionView.insertSubLayer(actionGradient, at: 0)

    return cell
}
```

And just for a reference my CUSTOM_GRADIENTS is a class that is initialized at in the ApplicationDelegate:

```
class safeGradiants {

    var blueToGreen: CAGradientLayer!

    init() {

        self.blueToGreen = CAGradientLayer()
        self.blueToGreen.colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.]
        self.blueToGreen.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        self.blueToGreen.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    }
}
```

Where the error occurs is when my tableView is loaded, the only cell with the gradient is the LAST CELL in the table view. I can only presume this has something to do with the reuse of cells, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this gradient showing on the actionView for all the cells?

Comment: if all the cells will have the same gradients applied, it is probably best to do this in the awakeFromNib() method of the table view cell, rather than do this in cellForRow

Comment: No, I can't do that because the cell dimensions aren't laid out at the time when awakeFrom() is called. But I was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of messing around, I figured out my problem lied in my safeGradients class. Since I was using one global instance of that class, I was un able to reuse the same variable blueToGreen.

The solution to this is instead of creating a class and having one global instance of that class, is to create an extension of CAGradientLayer that hosts subclass functions. In other words, I changed this code:

```
class safeGradiants {

var blueToGreen: CAGradientLayer!

    init() {

        self.blueToGreen = CAGradientLayer()
        self.blueToGreen.colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.]
        self.blueToGreen.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        self.blueToGreen.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    }
}
```

into this code:

```
extension CAGradientLayer {

    class var blueToGreen: CAGradientLayer {
        let blueToGreen = CAGradientLayer()
        blueToGreen.colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.green]
        blueToGreen.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        blueToGreen.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        return blueToGreen
    }
}
```